# set OnFocusChangeListener for more editTexts in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to set automatic scroll for each EditText(VerifiedEditText in my case) I have.
I did it this way but I don't think it is the way it should be done (looks too complicated, messy and too long), would you please recommend me making it anyway simpler? I am still learning by myself, so an explanation to attached code would be really appreciated. Thank you

```
@Override
public void onFocusScroll() {

final ScrollView mScrollView;    
mScrollView = (ScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.register_scroll);

        final VerifiedEditText editText0 = (VerifiedEditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.register_ticket);
        final VerifiedEditText editText1 = (VerifiedEditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.register_sektor);
        final VerifiedEditText editText2 = (VerifiedEditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.register_row);
        final VerifiedEditText editText3 = (VerifiedEditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.register_seat);

        editText0.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mScrollView.getTop());
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mScrollView.getBottom());
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        editText2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mScrollView.getBottom());
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        editText3.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mScrollView.getBottom());
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

---

Comment: Let your class `implements View.OnFocusChangeListener` and set same listener to all .Or if you want to do different task for each one then use `View v` --> `v.getId()`.

Comment: Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     implement class by `View.OnFocusChangeListener`
```

and set Focus Listener to the current instanace of class because treat as `View.OnFocusChangeListener` instnace 
and Override `onFocusChange()`  medthod

`v.getTop()` return top position of current focused view

```
 editText0.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
 editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
 editText2.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
 editText3.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);




            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {

                    mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, v.getTop());
                        }
                    });




}
                }
            }
```

Comment: So I have implemented OnFocusChangeListener to my main class, how can I use it in my method called onFocusScroll? My Override is always underlined. Sorry for this stupid question

Comment: OnFocusChangeListener is Interface you must implement her methods as it definded

see this tutorial https://www.javatpoint.com/interface-in-java

Comment: This is the thing I understand, but making public class Fragment extends BaseFragment implements OnFocusChangeListener - implement method. So I have got implemented method OnFocusChange. Now the thing I need to know is where do I put the findViewById of all EditTexts, cuz taking it to my method onFocusScroll (As seen above ) makes it total unuseable.

Comment: In onfocusScroll () method add findViewById then add setOnFocusChnageListener(this), outside the onfocusScroll () method override onfocusChange() method

Comment: Thank you for helping, I made a stupid mistake (I was using wrong Boolean). Again thanks for your time :), glad there is always someone to help.